# recover lost formulas in excel csv

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I realised I was working on a csv file in excel 2013 and inserting some formulas in this csv file columns.

After I saved and came back to it, the changed values persist but the formulas do not show anymore and I need to recover these.

Is there a way? Does excel maintain formulas after it is saved and file is closed and re-opened?

is there any way I can get it back?

Comment: No, the formulas are not kept if you save as a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not but you can check at: <sup><kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Open</kbd></sup> → <sub>[image: Recover Unsaved]</sub> .

---

That should have given you a warning by default, but if not you can enable the warning in:

```
<kbd>File</kbd></sup> → <sup><kbd>Options</kbd></sup> → <sup><kbd>Save</kbd></sup> : <sub>![dataloss msg][2]</sub>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes...
It may be possible. If it is Office 2010. Try this:

1. Open your excel
2. Go to File
3. Go to Manage Versions
4. Click Recover Unsaved Worksheets
5. Put your computer username in the following blank region.
   C:\Users\ ______\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel
6. Copy the above address then
7. Paste in the address bar
8. Select the appropriate folder and see the file

Thanks